# Does "subsequent" only refer to the direct successor?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

Oxford Learner's Dictionaries [defines subsequent](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/subsequent?q=subsequent) as *happening or coming after something else* but it is not very clear if it can still be used if there is another of the same thing between the two subsequent things.

For example, in the series 1 2 3

2 is *subsequent* to 1. 3 is *subsequent* to 2. Is 3 *subsequent* to 1, too?

If yes, how can I call the relation between 1/2 and 2/3 so that it can be distinguished from the relation which 1/3 have?
Something like *2 is **directly** subsequent to 1* or so? Are 1 and 2 ***directly*** subsequent? Is that correct English?

Comment: Hi Rob - I think I understand what you're asking, so I added some detail to make it more clear. If I misunderstood, you can roll back my changes by clicking on the "edited" link above my icon.

Answer (score 3):

[The meaning of subsequent is simply "following" or "coming after"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent), as you discovered, but it does not necessarily mean *immediately* or *directly* following.

Here are some examples that show how the word is used:

> [Subsequent educational attainment of high school dropouts](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lp2GmTZRLF8C&q=subsequent&dq=subsequent&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixiI3Smo_QAhWk7YMKHbBXBXkQ6AEIQzAH)

Here, "subsequent" means "coming later", but it obviously doesn't mean "right after dropping out of high school".

> [...scholars have not paid adequate attention to the twelve subsequent proceedings conducted in that city by the U.S. Army...](https://books.google.com/books?id=NnPBlkKk8AQC&pg=PA75&dq=subsequent&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJxo3om4_QAhUB84MKHfKsD044KBDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=subsequent&f=false)

Obviously, all of the twelve proceedings were subsequent to the first.

So yes, I would say that 3 is subsequent to 1 in your example, although to make things completely clear, I might say that it's *one of the subsequent things*.

---

If you want to specify "the very next one", I would suggest that the best term to use is *[immediately subsequent](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22immediately%20subsequent%22)* (although *[directly subsequent](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22directly%20subsequent%22)* is pretty good too).  For example,

> [...the correlation between each month and the immediately subsequent month was calculated...](https://books.google.com/books?id=d2IlHDNABU4C&pg=RA12-PA17&dq=%22immediately%20subsequent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-sJConY_QAhVKwYMKHQcwDtQQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22immediately%20subsequent%22&f=false)

Here "immediately subsequent" means "the very next month".

> [...prepare Bradfield's balance sheet immediately subsequent to the acquisition.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ezJ7LIl0U0oC&pg=PT193&dq=%22immediately%20subsequent%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKrbjSnY_QAhUIxYMKHTEMDu04ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22immediately%20subsequent%22&f=false)

Again, "immediately subsequent to" means "right after".

---

You can say that 2 is *immediately subsequent to* 1,  but I wouldn't say that 1 and 2 "are immediately subsequent", because one of them is subsequent to the other, saying "1 and 2 are immediately subsequent" makes it sound like they both come after something else.

Comment: Thank you so much so far! What can I say instead of "1 and 2 are immediately subsequent" if I would like to express that one of both is immediately subsequent to the other in a series but the order doesn't matter without the possibility to be misunderstood in the sense that both come after something else?

Comment: @Rob "Successive" or "consecutive" might fit

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, subsequent can be used for items that do not directly succeed the reference item.

A simple word for the immediately subsequent item is 'next'. For instance, "After 1, 3 is not next, but 2 is."